# How to find Chi square value of a bimodal Gaussain fitting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, astronomy, chi-squared, model-fitting

I write below this code;

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data=concatenate((normal(1,.2,5000),normal(2,.2,2500)))
y,x,_=hist(data,100,alpha=.3,label='data')

x=(x[1:]+x[:-1])/2 # for len(x)==len(y)

def gauss(x,mu,sigma,A):
    return A*exp(-(x-mu)**2/2/sigma**2)

def bimodal(x,mu1,sigma1,A1,mu2,sigma2,A2):
    return gauss(x,mu1,sigma1,A1)+gauss(x,mu2,sigma2,A2)

expected=(1,.2,250,2,.2,125)
params,cov=curve_fit(bimodal,x,y,expected)
sigma=sqrt(diag(cov))
plot(x,bimodal(x,*params),color='red',lw=3,label='model')
legend()
print(params,'\n',sigma)
```

I got this plot:

[image: I got this plot]

Now, I want to test the goodness of the fitting by calculating the value of chi square, How I find out the value of chi square?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do the folliwng, exploiting numpys array operation-functionality

```
import numpy as np

diff = np.array(bimodal(x,*params)) - np.array(y)
chi2 = np.sum( diff**2 / np.array(sigma)**2 )
```